# What is the difference between F+ (closure of F) and F* (cover of F) for Functional Dependencies?

Tags: relational-algebra, functional-dependencies, database-theory

F+ and F* are defined as follows:

- **F+: closure of F**

  - F+ = {fd | F |= fd}
  - Set of all FDs deduced from inference rule (normally: Armstrong axioms)
- **F*: cover of F**

  - F* = {fd | F |- fd}
  - Set of all FDs entailed by F (all FDs that are true)

So my question is: What is the difference between F+ and F*? Can you also give an example to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55093/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate on CS.SE, where it has already been reposted.

Comment: x is entailed by y means the same thing as x is deducible from y. However these definitions are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important property of the Armstrong’s axioms, (as well as of similar set of axioms), it that they are sound and complete (for a proof see for instance [this](http://kolany.pl/zajecia/2000-07/pwsz_2007-08/IS/bazy/materialy/slajdy/work/www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~csc3170b/Lectures/proofL.pdf)).

This amount to say that F<sup>+</sup> = F<sup>*</sup>. In other words, all the FD derived from those axioms are logically entailed by F, as well as all the FD dependencies logically entailed by F can be derived by repeatedly applying the axioms.

Comment: So your saying that they both essentially equivalent

Comment: Exactly, they are equivalent.

Comment: This is so odd. I'm glad I asked this question is "Computer Science" Stack Exchange and I got the complete opposite answer in that F+ and F* and completely different: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55093/what-is-the-difference-between-f-closure-of-f-and-f-cover-of-f-for-functio/55097#55097 . Note I only asked here as well because I was not sure how popular "Computer Science" Stack Exchange is.

Comment: @YahyaUddin, in the other answer there is a confusion between the closure of a set of attributes (the answer) and the closure of a set of functional dependencies (your question). You can read any book on normalization theory and see that the definition of the closure of a set of attributes (X+) is completely different from the closure of a set of functional dependencies (F+).

Comment: @YahyaUddin & Renzo The question definitions are wrong for those terms & the terms do not mean the same thing. This answer focuses on the phrases that are being used as the wrong definitions & doesn't point out that the terms mean different things & the definitions are wrong.